# Explain Pagination in grails

Tags: grails

I read the documents about pagination and im still confused about it

```
 <g:paginate controller="book" action="list" total="${bookCount}" />
```

is  total the one controlling how many is shown per page? if not what does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html):

> `max` (optional) - The number of records to display per page (defaults to 10). Used ONLY if params.max is empty

Comment: So since default is 10 I just need to put  
 <g:paginate controller="book" action="list" total="${bookCount}" />
on my view and I already have my pagination? No need to do something in controller?

Comment: @RedViper could you please see the (linked) docs, which contain a full example (including a Controller). And since the the original question was about the items per page, if you have further questions: please add another one, since SO is a QA format.